# AppRegistry is not a registered callable module when i use CheckBox

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

when i use checkbox

i used this CheckBox from react-native

```
 import {CheckBox} from 'react-native';
```

but when i use this some waring occure which is this

Warning: CheckBox has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/checkbox' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-checkbox

so i changed my code accoring to document

import { CheckBox } from 'react-native';

to:

import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

but if i use

```
 import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
```

this error occure

> Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable
> module (calling unmountApplicationComponentAtRootTag)

so what can i do?? how to fix??

Comment: Did you install @react-native-community/checkbox ?

Comment: @bryanstevens314 yes i did and i  also checked  in package.json

Comment: Might need to clear the cache or reinstall node_modules, these errors can be tricky sometimes. Checkout this link for a solution https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26687